# OpenBSD Supported Hardware

Tags: networking, hardware, openbsd, laptop, firmware

I've recently installed OpenBSD on my Lenovo Ideapad 510s-14ISK. Unfortunately, it seems that my current network card (Qualcomm Atheros NFA435 QCA9377-5 / NFA 344 QCA6174 WiFi 802.11ac 1x1 + BT) is unsupported, which I have learned through the following dmesg printout:

```
vendor "Atheros", unknown product 0x0052 (class network subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x30) at pci3 dev 0 function 0 not configured
```

Anyways, I'm looking into replacing this part with a supported one. However, I have had no luck with finding a supported hardware list for OpenBSD. I'd like some advice from you folks out there, and a link to a hardware list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Wireless):

> OpenBSD has support for [a number of wireless chipsets](https://man.openbsd.org/?query=wireless&apropos=1).

Which brings you to the OpenBSD man pages for all wireless drivers. Read through the drivers you are interested in to find the supported hardware. Most things you need to know can be found in the man pages this way.

For example, from the [iwm](https://man.openbsd.org/man4/iwm.4)(4) man page:

> The iwm driver provides support for **Intel Wireless 7260, 7265, 3160, 3165, 3168, 8260, and 8265** PCIe Mini Card network adapters.

Remember that some hardware requires non-free firmware to be installed before it can work. This firmware isn't included in the base install, and will typically be installed after first boot using the [fw_update](https://man.openbsd.org/fw_update)(1) utility.

Comment: I have attempted to use the fw_update utility, but unfortunately it did not fix my problems. I didn't know about the driver man pages, though, so thank you for telling me about that!

Comment: I have found my solution! One of the network cards supported by iwm(4) is compatible with my laptop! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Meander51 You are welcome! Glad you found what you needed!

Comment: When installing it in a notebook, I usually install it with a supported ralink USB, and only then configure the notebook's wifi.